# Rails difference in exception debug output for same object

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a User model and a List model in my app.

pages_controller.rb

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

 def home
  if user_signed_in?
   @lists = current_user.lists    
   # raise @lists.inspect 
   @new_list = current_user.lists.build
  end
 end

end
```

pages/home.html.erb

```
<%= raise @lists.inspect %>
```

Now, my current user has no lists associated with him .
When I uncomment the 3rd line in "Pages#home"

```
raise @lists.inspect
```

I get the output like so :

```
 []
```

But, when I comment that line out, then the exception inside home.html.erb is raised , and its output is like so : `[#<List id: nil, name: nil, description: nil, user_id: 1, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>]`

Why is there a difference in output for the same `@lists.inspect` line ?

EDIT : When I use `@lists = current_user.lists.all` instead of `@lists = current_user.lists`  then I get an empty array at both places . Why the difference in behavior between the 2 codes ?

Answer (score 1):

Because you build `lists` in the controller *after* the first `raise`:

```
@new_list = current_user.lists.build
```

It's the same code, but the *data* is different, because you *did* something to it.

Comment: Ah ..Thats it . When I removed this `@new_list = current_user.lists.build` , then it shows same output . But the empty array has already been assigned to @lists ,so why should the next line make any difference ? I'm confused

Comment: And, when I use    `@lists = current_user.lists.all` , then the output in both cases is `[]` . So , why the difference ?

Comment: @Inreddy Because there's a difference between an association with no members and one with a single default member, which is what is created when you build with no parameters.

Comment: I'm sorry for being dense here , but what I meant was ,if I replace the line `@lists = current_user.lists` with `@lists = current_user.lists.all` , then I get an empty array in both places .So why does `@lists = current_user.lists.all` behave differently ?